# XSLT – Compare node values and pass attributes if nodes are equal

Tags: xslt

I am trying to do something that is probably very simple, but my very rudimentary xslt is not up to it.
Given the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MyLists>
    <List1>
        <Place01 ctr="PTG">Lisbon</Place01>
        <Place02 ctr="SPA">Madrid</Place02>
        <Place03 ctr="FRA">Paris</Place03>
        <Place04 ctr="ENG">York</Place04>
    </List1>
    <List2>
        <Item01 type="country">Italy</Item01>
        <Item02 type="person">John</Item02>
        <Item03 type="city">York</Item03>
        <Item04 type="city" subtype="capital">Madrid</Item04>
    </List2>
</MyLists>
```

I would like to compare the text nodes from `<List1>` and `<List2>`, and, whenever their values are the same, pass, for each element, the attributes from `<List2>` to the corresponding items in `<List1>`, in order to get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MyLists>
    <List1>
        <Place01 ctr="PTG">Lisbon</Place01>
        <Place02 ctr="SPA" type="city" subtype="capital">Madrid</Place02>
        <Place03 ctr="FRA">Paris</Place03>
        <Place04 ctr="ENG" type="city">York</Place04>
    </List1>
    <List2>
        <Item01 type="country">Italy</Item01>
        <Item02 type="person">John</Item02>
        <Item03 type="city">York</Item03>
        <Item04 type="city" subtype="capital">Madrid</Item04>
    </List2>
</MyLists>
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to copy whichever attributes these element possess, without having to specify them.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you could do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="match" match="Item" use="." />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Place">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('match', .)/@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I should have specified that I would like to be able to copy and add attributes only, in order to preserve possibly existing attributes in the first list, and whatever the name of the elements.  I have edited the original example accordingly. Many thanks!

Comment: @Robin If you want to copy existing attributes then add `<xsl:copy-of select=@*"/>` either before or immediately after `<xsl:copy-of select="key('match', .)/@*"/>`. Note that attributes with the same name will be overwritten.